# Installing PHP Driver for Cassandra on Windows 7 with Xampp

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I'm trying to implement https://github.com/datastax/php-driver on Windows 7 with Xampp.

I've downloaded all the required dependencies.

When I execute vc_build, it hangs or stops after printing "Building and installing cpp-driver".

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&ik=3b8c444a04&view=fimg&th=14fc7e601acf5f83&attid=0.1&disp=emb&realattid=ii_14fc7e23a10fc709&attbid=ANGjdJ9tOvdH26loNZ57M5zPRWYH2opB0gvFwChzXhjoSqBiU2KFDdkVVgee2prFMOquD36Lvi5JbwDyUd0Jz_N1bJaptmH9b0ztDGv1pYA09fduehZI8fFPXXT0abI&sz=w908-h448&ats=1443579568911&rm=14fc7e601acf5f83&zw&atsh=1

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing using pecl?

https://github.com/datastax/php-driver/blob/master/ext/README.md#installing-with-pecl